# How to chart data for months at a time?

Tags: c#, database, charts

I have an industrial application that needs to chart temperature and pressure every 5 minutes for several months (up to 9 months). I have it set up already, but if the computer crashes, the data is lost. What is the best way to store this data so that the application can recover after a crash? Moreover, due to the fact that there are thousands of data points, what is the optimal way to display them?

Comment: How are you storing them at the moment? How are you filtering and displaying the data at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most simple, least optimal:**

Store the date in a flat text file. Append each new log value to the end of the file.

**More work required, more optimal:**

Create a database and write your values into there